# Bangla font not showing in cakephp when data retrieve from mysql database

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp version 2.7 . In my view I van show static bangla. But when I get data from database then bangla font not working.

Comment: Did you set `utf8_general_ci` for Database `Collation`?

Comment: yes. I also do it. Mysql also save bangla data. But not showing in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Check your `layout` file have below line -

For **HTML5**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Also set your Database `Collation` to `utf8_general_ci`

> Search and Uncomment below line from `app/Config/database.php` file

```
//'encoding' => 'utf8',
```

TO

```
'encoding' => 'utf8',
```